# Algorithm to calculate n digits of pi in C++?

Tags: c++

Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double pi = 0;
    long i;
    long n;
    
    cout << "Enter the value of n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
          pi = pi + (1 / (2 * i + 1));
      else
          pi = pi - (1 / (2 * i + 1));
        pi = 4 * pi;
    }
    
    cout << endl << "pi = " << pi << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, this does not give the desired output. For example, n = 9, pi = 262144. I know it's possible to just store pi as a constant and get the result that way, but I'm wondering what I am doing wrong using the algorithm above.

Comment: And even if we replace `1` with `1.0`, the sequence of `pi` values still goes to infinity as `n` increases.  (You can demonstrate that easily by print `pi` inside the loop.)  Can you please explain what infinite mathematical sum you are trying to evaluate and why you think it should equal π?  Or at least link to the explanation.  The [series shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284406/pi-as-an-infinite-series-using-taylor-expansion-on-equation-of-a-circle#:~:text=This%20can%20be%20written%20as,(2n%E2%88%921)!) looks more likely to work than yours.

Comment: I am trying to calculate n digits of pi. For example, 9 -> 3.25237 where n is input.

Comment: Do you mind posting the fixed version that closely resembles the code provided?

Comment: Is this homework?  Why not make an actual attempt yourself?

Comment: "3.25237" is not 9 digits of pi.  It's only 6 digits long and the second digit is wrong (should be 1 instead of 2).

Comment: Are you trying to use Leibniz infinite series? Then you should only multiply by 4 at the end of the series, not within each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `long i;`, `(1 / (2 * i + 1))` will be zero for any `i>0`.
When `i=0`, you got `pi=1;`
for `i=1,9`, you got `pi = 4*pi;`
That's why you got `262144` which is `4^8`.

You might want

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0)
      pi = pi + (1.0 / (2 * i + 1));
  else
      pi = pi - (1.0 / (2 * i + 1));
}
pi = 4 * pi;
```

Comment: Now I get 972340.

Comment: Something wrong in your algorithm. I guess you need to move ```pi = 4 * pi;``` out of the ```for``` loop.

Comment: It works after I moved ```pi = 4*pi;``` out of the ```for``` loop. I got 3.25237 for ```n=9```.